# Issue with file system android Quick Question

Tags: android

I have an app that saves files to the sd card but apparently some people that use the app don't see the file until they restart their phone. How can I fix this?

Comment: do you call the close() or the flush() method on the FileOutputStream?

Comment: IMO problem is that some Android devices do refresh its state after every sd-card write and some are not. That is how unix-based system works. When you mount some drive and do some stuff there (write/delete) everything is actually written on that drive on umount momentum. That is just IMO!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar scenarios where files are not visible until application is closed. May be your users may "force close" the application just to be sure is an issue with your application.

My guess is that you may be are not closing the OutputStream object you use to write the files on the SD card, I mean, call out.close() method, where out is an instance of OutputStream.